# How to calculate concordant percentage in a validation data

Tags: logistic, concordance

I've created a logistic regression model in R using the glm function using a bank data and.  I am able to  get the AIC value, coefficients, percentage concordant, tied and discordant pairs in test and training data.  But I have a validation data set where the status of the customer(good or bad) is not there as I have to check the performance of the model using this validation data.   What should be my approach?

Answer (score 1):

The concordant percentage cannot be computed without knowing the actuals (status of the customer, in your case). However, they can likely be estimated from the value computed on the training set. Under simplified assumptions the concordant percentage is apparently normally distributed around $d/\sqrt{2}$, where $d$ is Cohen's effect size. See [Austin & Steyerberg](http://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-12-82).